# How to install and active solr with AWS VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, solr, amazon-vpc

I Have AWS server's VPC configuration and need to install solr with the existing credential.

Please help me

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This site offers assistance for software development questions. You might find [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/) to be a better venue for this question - it is for Systems Administrators.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use [Amazon CloudSearch](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/what-is-cloudsearch.html), which is a **managed Solr service** (with a few differences).

The benefit is that AWS takes care of installation, configuration and running the servers for you.